# You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I got some strange and annoying problems after installing Gazebo 1.9 from source to be able to compile the gazebo_ros_pkgs.

I followed the installation instructions as shown in [Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages) and [Compiling_From_Source](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install#Compiling_From_Source). At this time the link pointing to the compiling_from_source of version 1.6. wasn't crossed out.

After the installation I was able to compile the gazebo_ros_pkgs in my catkin folder. But I got problems starting my models in Gazebo due to some ROS problems, saying something like:

> "Not loading plugin since ROS hasn't been properly initialized".

I wasn't able to fix that. But because I achieved to compile the plugin package I went back to Gazebo 1.8.6 and ROS 1.9.45. Therefore I completely uninstalled all the old Gazebo and ROS versions.

What happens now is -  when I try to start my models in Gazebo, using some self made plugins, I got the following error message:

[FATAL] [1373626195.720031658]: You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle
[FATAL] [1373626195.720081828]: BREAKPOINT HIT
file = /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-roscpp-1.9.44-0precise-20130325-1240/src/libros/node_handle.cpp
line=151

I got two plugins and both of them worked fine before I made the previously mentioned changes.

The strange thing is, this error message appears only with one of the plugins. And they both initialize ros in the same way.

```
    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
        // Start up ROS
        std::string name = "scitos_gazebo_platform_control";
        int argc = 0;
        ros::init(argc, NULL, name);


        // ROS Nodehandle
        this->my_rosnode = new ros::NodeHandle("~");
                    ...
```

When I try to comment the rosnode or to get an message to the console by only using std::cout the error message stay the same.

Thank you for your help.

Christoph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3557/you-must-call-ros::init()-before-creating-the-first-nodehandle/) by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-12**:
The Code you posted here does not seem to be the Problem!

btw. std::cout does not pipe the message directly to the console(it is buffered first). If you want to use an console output for debuging use std::err.
this is the same for all C/C++ apllications.

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2013-07-12**:
The Code you posted here does not seem to be the Problem!

btw. std::cout does not pipe the message directly to the console(it is buffered first). If you want to use an console output for debuging use std::err.
this is the same for all C/C++ apllications.

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-12**:
you seem to have two questions here... 1) properly installing and running gazebo and 2) fixing your custom plugin. it would be easier if we had 1 question per topic.
for 1) how are you starting gazebo?

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-07-17**:
@evilBiber: I used std:err during my problem analysis, but that didn't give me an output either. Thanks for the information about the operation principles of std::cout though.   @davetcoleman: before I tried Gazebo 1.9. everything worked fine for me. At some point I installed DRCSim too, to get the laser plugin. I start Gazebo from the console typing "gazebo" and then insert my model from the gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Finally reinstalling ROS and all Gazebo components from source worked for me. See my newer question [4026](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4026/installing-gazebo-19-and-gazebo_ros_pkgs-from/).

I changed nothing in my code regarding the ROS initialization.

---

Originally posted by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) with karma: 141 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0